# When does Cascade Delete Commit in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

This is my sql set of statements:

```
char *sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Friends(id varchar UNIQUE); 
CREATE TABLE Enemies(id2 varchar ,id3 INTEGER,CONSTRAINT id_econst
FOREIGN KEY(id2) REFERENCES Friends(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('11');
INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('2');
INSERT INTO Enemies VALUES('11',3);
INSERT INTO Enemies VALUES('3',5);
END TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
DELETE FROM Friends WHERE id = '11';";
```

Performs cascade delete on the Enemies table, whereas :

```
 char *sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Friends(id varchar UNIQUE); 
CREATE TABLE Enemies(id2 varchar ,id3 INTEGER,CONSTRAINT id_econst
FOREIGN KEY(id2) REFERENCES Friends(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('11');
INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('2');
INSERT INTO Enemies VALUES('11',3);
INSERT INTO Enemies VALUES('3',5);
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
DELETE FROM Friends WHERE id = '11';
END TRANSACTION;";
```

does normal delete.

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enabling foreign key support within the transaction. To quote sqlite:

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction

https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys

In your second example, the pragma has no effect, and the foreign key constraint is not enforced.